# Pele Yoetz Question

Tags: sources-mekorot, music, mussar-ethics

Does someone know from which chapter of the Pele Yoetz this is taken or paraphrased from?

> There is a general rule in life, that we believe with perfect faith
> nothing bad comes from heaven, it is only good and it is all good

Shimon Levi composed a song he sings with Yaakov Shwekey ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WR-kZWo97Ho)) and they state it is from Pele Yoetz.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pele Yoetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele_Yoetz), published in 1824, is a compilation of essential Jewish concepts. As such, some of its sayings are sourced in earlier texts. This saying is found in the Talmud, tractate [Berachot page 60b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60b.12?lang=bi)

> Rav Huna said that Rav said that Rabbi Meir said; and so it was taught
> in a baraita in the name of Rabbi Akiva: **One must always accustom
> oneself to say: Everything that God does, He does for the best.**

Once you know that, it is easy to find it five times in Pele Yoetz chapters [143:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Pele_Yoetz.143.3?vhe=Torat_Emet&lang=bi), [218:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pele_Yoetz.218.1?vhe=Torat_Emet&lang=bi), [238:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Pele_Yoetz.238.6?vhe=Torat_Emet&lang=bi), [312:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pele_Yoetz.312.1?vhe=Torat_Emet&lang=bi), [402:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pele_Yoetz.402.1?vhe=Torat_Emet&lang=bi)